# How do I prevent Skype notifications during a call

Tags: skype, ubuntu-11.10

If I am on a Skype call with a person (with Share Screen Option switched ON), I don't want to get notified if someone calls me or messages me. They shouldn't know who my contacts are. What should I do in order to achieve this?

Comment: FWIW: Would be great if Skype added a setting to always suppress notifications during a call. Then wouldn’t have to do this each time (especially when someone else initiated the call). And wouldn’t need to remember to enable notifications again when call ends.

Answer (score 0):

You simply go to the Skype preferences/settings and turn visual notifications off.

Comment: do let me know how to reach the skype preference settings. i am unable to get there

Comment: I might have been answering this questions too quickly. Are there no preferences/options/settings for the Linux version?